# How to integrate Spnego into Spring WebFlux security

Tags: spring, spring-webflux

There are some non-WebFlux Spnego helper classes in the Spring Framework: `SpnegoEndpoint` which is a filter for sending back the correct response codes and `SnegoAuthenticationProcessingFilter` for processing the token from the browser. HOWEVER, I can't find any information on the equivalent SPNEGO setup for WebFlux.

Is it possible to use SPNEGO authentication with WebFlux?